# Issue with macro and `buffer-name`

Tags: elisp-macros

I want to write a macro that makes a `diffpdf` before and after some changes in my `LaTeX` file (that would be compiled twice by `pdflatex`).

I tried:

```el
(defmacro with-diffpdf-after-changes (&rest body)
  "DOCSTRING"
  (declare (indent 1))
  (let* ((FILE_NAME (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-name)))
         (PDF_FILE (concat FILE_NAME ".pdf")))

    `(progn
       (save-buffer)
       (call-process-shell-command
        (concat "pdflatex \"\\let\\oldExecuteOptions\\ExecuteOptions\"\\\n"
                "\"\\def\\ExecuteOptions#1{\\oldExecuteOptions{#1,draft}}\"\\\n"
                "\"\\nonstopmode\\input{" (buffer-name) "}\";"
                "mv "  ,PDF_FILE " /tmp/"  )
        nil nil)

       ,@body

       (save-buffer)
       (call-process-shell-command
        (concat "pdflatex \"\\let\\oldExecuteOptions\\ExecuteOptions\"\\\n"
                "\"\\def\\ExecuteOptions#1{\\oldExecuteOptions{#1,draft}}\"\\\n"
                "\"\\nonstopmode\\input{" (buffer-name) "}\";"
                "diffpdf -a " ,PDF_FILE " /tmp/" ,PDF_FILE )
        nil nil)

       )
    ))
```

But something's wrong with my code. `PDF_FILE` is named by the file that calls the macro while I need it to be named by the buffer of my LaTeX file.

E.g. my LaTeX file is `paper.tex`, the macro is called by a function in the file `replacements.el`

I get that the macro makes `diffpdf` look for `./replacements.pdf` and `/tmp/replacements.pdf`

I need `diffpdf paper.pdf /tmp/paper.pdf`.

Comment: Macros are expanded at compile time, not (generally) at run-time.  Any code which you need to be evaluated at run-time *must* be part of the code generated (returned) by the macro.  Your `let` bindings are happening outside of that.

Comment: Further to what Phil wrote, see [`(info "(elisp) Problems with Macros")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Problems-with-Macros.html).

Comment: @Basil I had already red the page you suggested... but I'm getting lost in the expansion.  I'm not really sure of what i'm doing.

Comment: Finally it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My let-bindings was outside the quoted part.

The working code is:

```el
(defmacro with-diffpdf-after-changes (&rest body)
  "DOCSTRING"
  (declare (indent 1))

  `(progn
     (let* ((FILE_NAME (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-name)))
            (PDF_FILE (concat FILE_NAME ".pdf")))
       (save-buffer)
       (call-process-shell-command
        (concat "pdflatex \"\\let\\oldExecuteOptions\\ExecuteOptions\"\\\n"
                "\"\\def\\ExecuteOptions#1{\\oldExecuteOptions{#1,draft}}\"\\\n"
                "\"\\nonstopmode\\input{" (buffer-name) "}\";"
                "mv "  PDF_FILE " /tmp/"  )
        nil nil)

       ,@body

       (save-buffer)
       (call-process-shell-command
        (concat "pdflatex \"\\let\\oldExecuteOptions\\ExecuteOptions\"\\\n"
                "\"\\def\\ExecuteOptions#1{\\oldExecuteOptions{#1,draft}}\"\\\n"
                "\"\\nonstopmode\\input{" (buffer-name) "}\";"
                "diffpdf -a " PDF_FILE " /tmp/" PDF_FILE )
        nil nil)

       )
     ))
```

Thanks to phils and Basil for their usefull comments.

Comment: Please consider describing what your correction amounts to, to help readers understand and not just have to diff the code and attempt to work it out on their own. Thx.

Comment: @Drew, I have an idea of what I've done, but it's not easy to me to tecnically explain it. I just put the let-binding part into the backquoted one (right?).

Comment: Whatever you think best describes the fix/answer, please add that to the answer.